# Redirect 301 PHP

Tags: php, redirect, shopify

Мне нужно сделать некоторые редиректы для сайта, однако shopify не дает изменять файл .htaccess. Не могу разобраться как это сделать

1. Нужно при помощи редиректа 301 убрать слеши и двойные слеши в конце url со всех страниц сайта
2. Нужно при помощи редиректа 301 сделать, чтобы все ссылки были только с буквами в нижнем регистре для всех страниц сайта
3. Нужно убрать с конца url часть index.html и main.html со всех страниц сайта

Comment: Так если нужно – сделайте, мы не против :)

Answer (score 0):

Shopify не дает доступ к файлам на сервере.
В Shopify учитывают проблему дублей при краулинге поисковыми системами, указывая, что для всех url продукции /collections/./products/ канонической является страница /products/ и именно её нужно индексировать. Но при этом Shopify в своей внутренней перелинковке сайта по умолчанию ссылается на вторичные ссылки /collections/./products/ а не на первичные /products/.

И хотя тег canonical зачастую верно работает при обходе сайта роботами поисковых систем, помните, что Google рассматривает canonical как рекомендации, а не правило.

или

Попробуйте решить проблему в админке нажав Online Store -> Navigation -> URL Redirects -> Add URL redirect. Здесь вы можете добавить перенаправление со старого URL на новый.

Comment: как-то это не очень похоже на ответы на заданные вопросы. да, в нарушение правил автором вопроса задано несколько несвязанных вопросов, но и из вашего ответа не очень понятно, на какой именно из вопросов вы отвечаете.

Comment: Удалите мой ответ раз не нравится.